# Moving Files on Android File System as Signed System App

Tags: android, android-source

I am currently developing Kiosk style app, with a custom AOSP image my team build from source. The app runs with the system process id, in the system/priv-app folder and is signed by the OS key. Generally privileged actions complete fine. However as part of a first boot activity after an upgrade, we need to move files from the /system/ folder to the apps data directory, so far when doing this using Java File IO, I'm getting a `java.io.FileNotFoundException: <file path> (Permission denied)` when attempt to move or even copy the file.

I'm wondering if there is some hidden permission I need to declare or some other approach

Comment: AFAIK you'll need root permissions ( uid 0 ) to do that, system_process permissions wont suffice. I'd suggest you do this in an init.rc file where you have root.

Comment: In my investigation since I've come to same conclusion. Tried it via adb shell from a terminal, which runs as root. However running it in the app itself, I can see the user is system not root and it fails. The init.rc is a good shout I think!